# How to find the number of Inserts and Updates of Merge command?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, delta-lake

I have code similar to this in Spark(Scala). I would like to know the number of records this code updated/inserted when `execute()` is complete. Is there a way?

```scala
 deltaTable
     .as("target")
     .merge(
       source.as("source"),
       "target.key = source.key")
     .whenMatched
     .updateExpr(Map(
       "value" -> "source.value"))
     .whenNotMatched
     .insertExpr(Map(
       "key" -> "source.key",
       "value" -> "source.value"))
     .execute()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get this data from the [Delta table history](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-utility.html#operation-metrics-keys&language-scala) - in Scala it's just

```scala
val lastOperationDF = deltaTable.history(1)
```

Then you get DataFrame, where you have the `operationMetrics` column that is a map from metric name to value. According to the [documentation about metrics](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-utility.html#operation-metrics-keys), information that you need is in the keys `numTargetRowsInserted` & `numTargetRowsUpdated`.

Comment: this is still an open feature request 
https://github.com/delta-io/delta/issues/1361

Answer (score 0):

SQL Version:

```
select operation, 
       timestamp, 
       operationMetrics.numTargetRowsInserted,
       operationMetrics.numTargetRowsUpdated
  from (describe history delta.`your_table` limit 1)
 where operation = 'MERGE'
```

Depending on what you're doing you may need to change the where clause or the operationMetrics to what you're looking for